# CodeIgniter returning 404 if controller files are in lowercase on linux

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, http-status-code-404

I am using `CodeIgniter 3.0.3` and having problem in running my app on `linux`, It is returning 404 if `controller name` starts in `lowercase` character, If I rename the controller with first char in uppercase then it is working.

I've tried on xampp it is working there with controller name starts with lowercase character .

Is there any setting I have to change to make my app work with `controller name` starts in `lowercase`, or rename all controller with first char in uppercase?

I know that it is not a tough task to rename all the controllers, but I need to know if there is any workaround.

Thanks in advance for your precious time.

Comment: Also official link of [PHP Style Guide](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/styleguide.html) that is followed and/or recommended/demanded by CI.

Comment: In 2016 I want to see all URLs all lower case.  Hate upper case in URLs.  Just a visual hang-up I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Codeigniter 3 you have to create ***file names with caps in first***. File names means ***Model and Controller***.

> **And in Windows it will work when its in small capes. But in linux it will not. Its Case-Sensitive.**

[Naming Conventions in Codeigniter](http://ci3-userguide.cocomowebbeheer.nl/general/creating_libraries.html#naming-conventions)

Comment: @SwarnenduPaul check this as well

Comment: sure, thats why I gave you +1. Let me rename my files and run my app successfully

Comment: ah ok ok. Happy to help :) +1

Answer (score 1):

In codeigniter 3,controller and model  name must start with title case.ex- Home,Registration.

Window is not case-sensitive. Linux base server is case-sensitive.

Comment: but On XAMPP  it is working there with controller name starts with lowercase character @Shradda

Comment: Windows not check Case-Sensitive. But in linux it will not. Its Case-Sensitive.

Comment: @ShraddhaGajjar copied from mine. LOL :P

Comment: No.i reply to Swarnendu Paul question.

Comment: @ShraddhaGajjar Thanks for your ans too.